# how create JSON or list of lists of dictionary of dictionaries file from a txt file using python regex

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Hi i am familiar with python xmltree, json, pandas and numpy, XML parsing. today i got a huge text file to parse it almost looks like json format with little different, i understood if i can create dictionary of dictionaries like json my problem solved, but i am totally clueless how to convert to json, the below file

```
%Bank PARSED MESSAGE FILE
%VERSION   : PIL 98.7
%nex MODULE   : SIL 98

2018 Jan 31  16:44:53.050    
Pkt Version = 8


 name id ID = 0,  ID = 58
    Freq = 180

    conserved NEXT:

    value Name ::= 
    {
      message c1 : ABC1 : 
          {
            XYZ2 
            {
              Andhra 
              {
                {
                  Vizag
                  {
                    pool 
                    {
                      1,
                      2,
                      3
                    },
                    loop 
                    {
                      6,
                      7,
                      5
                    }
                  },
                  toll closed //
                }
              },
              toll code '00000000 00000001'B


2018 Jan 31  16:44:43.050    
Pkt Version = 8
name id ID = 1,  ID = 56
Freq = 567

conserved LATE:

World ::= 
{
  Asia c1 : EastAsia : 
      {
        India 
        {
          Tamil 
          {
            {
              Trichy
              {
                pool 
                {
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
                },
                loop 
                {
                  6,
                  7,
                  5
                }
              },
              toll closed //
            }
          },
          toll code '00000000 00000001'B
```

Comment: That doesn't quite look like valid json, not sure you'll get out of it without writing some custom parser

Comment: That's really not very close to JSON. And trying to parse it using regex would be even worse than parsing HTML with regex. I guess you could create a parser for it using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)

Comment: can you please suggest how to create such custom parser.. is there any steps or tutorial